# 80's/90's sci-fi movie about passengers on a ship crewed/commanded by people in sealed environments

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi movie I saw in the late 80's to early 90's, for some reason I want to say it was on Cinemax.

The highlights I can recall:

- The story focused on passengers on a large starship;
- Opening of the film was some type of facility or star port that featured a massive dome that was opening to either allow a ship/shuttle to land or launch (not positive about this, I just recall early in the film some time of massive dome opening up and passengers all gathering there);
- Ship was mostly automated, only crew were a mother and a son who survived in isolated environments (immunologically compromised or somehow modified so they couldn't be around normal humans);
- At one point the crew-son is in a sealed suit/pod and is helping a female passenger in a space suit travel along scaffolding;
- The crew-son is protecting/helping the passengers against his mother.

For some reason it reminded me of *The Ship Who Sang* series, except that it's a movie.

Comment: I've voted to close on the grounds that the movies sound extraordinarily similar.

Comment: Voted to reopen because unless there's a hidden deleted comment, I don't see any kind of acceptance in the dupe-target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds a bit like [*Nightflyers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093626/), a 1987 movie very loosely inspired by the [George R. R. Martin novella in the collection of the same name](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812545621).

From the IMDB link:

> Professor hires a spaceship to get to the source of weird signals from
>   deep space. The trip is cut short however when the ship's computer
>   gets jealous because the captain is in love with one of the female
>   passengers and it gets homicidal.

The "son" (owner-captain of the ship) was born and raised in space by his extremely paranoid-schizophrenic mother. He was never exposed to normal planetary germs or gravity so he's pretty much confined to his ship. His mother impressed her consciousness onto the ship's computer when she died - and she's quite jealous of anyone else interacting with her son.

Comment: That sounds pretty close, I'll read some more about it to be sure.

Comment: Amazing. I watched this movie 25 years ago and had forgotten all about it until today I started watching the Netflix original series by the same name and noticed some strange parallels. It's the same story.